# Recursively print and remove files matching one of two patterns

Tags: bash, find

I need it to search for all files - in the current directory as well as in its sub-directories - with a name ending by `~`, or a name that start and end by `#`.
Here's my code

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -exec -delete grep ^#.*#$ | grep .~$
```

Where's my mistake?

Comment: both `^` , `*` and `$` are special to the shell, try enclosing your grep pattern with single quotes, also you're already using `find` so why the `ls` ? Not to mention the `find` and `grep` combination looks wrong in your code.

Comment: @oguzismail, it's ok we have almost the same answer. only I don't have the `-print`

Comment: @oguzismail, judging from the OP's grep code, yours is correct.

Comment: the `-delete` flag will actually delete everything! make a dry run without first. and grep does just nothing. use `-iname` or `-name` like suggested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need grep for that.

```
find . -type f \( -name '*~' -o -name '#*#' \) -print # -delete
```

Uncomment `-delete` to remove the files it lists. You can substitute `-delete` with `-exec rm {} +` when the former is not available.